# Conditional formatting where two columns in a table are not the same

Tags: excel

I have a table called `promos` containing 2 columns `existing mechanic_code` and `new mechanic_code`. I want to format the values in those columns accordingly if they are not equal.

I tried this

```
=INDIRECT("promos[existing mechanic_code]")<>INDIRECT("promos[new mechanic_code]")
```

in my Conditional Formatting formula but it didn't have the desired affect. It evaluated to true for all cells (i.e. coloured them all red):

[image]

Here is an example of exactly what I mean: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjcmU60daA9VqsRFaZzng_w1gP_EWQ

I only want to highlight rows where the two columns are different.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this to make it work:-

```
=INDIRECT("table2[@old]")<>INDIRECT("table2[@new]")
```

where my column headings were just "old" & "new"

so yours should be

```
=INDIRECT("promos[@existing mechanic_code]")<>INDIRECT("promos[@new mechanic_code]")
```

But because you've put a space and an underscore in your column headers you will have to use instead:-

```
=INDIRECT("Promos[@[Existing Mechanic_Code]]")<>INDIRECT("Promos[@[New Mechanic_Code]]")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom. Didn;t work unfortunately, didn't highlight anything in the workbook I linked to earlier

Answer (score -1):

Please select B3:C6 and and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$B3<>$C3
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red Fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks but those are not table column references, which is what I want.